# Upload image to servlet from android client gives a corrupt file

Tags: java, android, image, servlets

I'm trying to upload an image to servlet from my android client. The code executes well, however when I try to open the sended image, it seems corrupted. ¿Do you know why?

The code is the next:

Android client:

```
            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, stream);//compress to which format you want.
            byte [] byte_arr = stream.toByteArray();
            String image_str = Base64.encodeToString(byte_arr, 0);
```

image_str is what I'm sending to servlet:

```
        byte[] imageByteArray = Base64.decode(message);
        FileOutputStream f = new FileOutputStream("/path/IMG/pruebaaaa.jpg");
        f.write(imageByteArray);
        f.close();
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: The code only shows how you compress, Base64-encode/decode and save the image. Although not SSCCE-worthy, that part looks somewhat legit. The problem is likely caused elsewhere. How are you actually sending the image to the servlet and retrieving it in the servlet?

Answer (score 0):

Try putting in flush() just above close() as below.

```
f.write(imageByteArray);
f.flush();
f.close();
```